# strange suggested template parameter conversion

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, pointer-to-member

On the book C++ templates - The Complete Guide, Vandevoorde & Josuttis, it was suggested the following snippet to determine whether a type is a class or not. The argument was: "For class types we can rely on the observation that the pointer to member type construct int C::* is valid only if C is a class type" as a strategy to decide whether a type is a "class" type or not.

I have two questions:

1) Do you think the argument is valid?
2) How would you modify (preserving the strategy) the snippet below to make it work, since it doesn't compile on MSVC2013?

```
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class IsClass
{
    typedef char One;
    typedef struct 
    { 
        char a[2];
    } Two;
    template<typename C> static One test(int C::*);
    template<typename C> static Two test(...);
public:
    enum { YES = (sizeof(IsClass<T>::test<T>(0) == 1)) };
};

class C{};

void main()
{
    if (IsClass<C>::YES)
        std::cout << "C Is a Class" << endl;
}
```

Comment: MSVS 2013 only has partial SFINAE support.  You might need to pick up MSVS 2015.

Comment: I know this is "argument from authority" but if either one of those authors make a claim about C++ I would want strong evidence (chapter and verse from the standard) to contradict it.  Specifically, if either of them disagreed with Bjarne Stroustrup about what the standard specified, I wouldn't want to place bets on who was right.  With both of them having reviewed the code, it will be right.

Comment: [Partial Support for Expression SFINAE in VS 2015 Update 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/12/02/partial-support-for-expression-sfinae-in-vs-2015-update-1.aspx). In 2013 version substitution failure IS an error. I do not see a workaround.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Even MSVC 2015 only has partial SFINAE support. They're throwing away the compiler and starting over. [Here's one of their blog posts about it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/09/25/rejuvenating-the-microsoft-c-c-compiler.aspx)

Comment: @AndyG Thanks for the link.  I didn't know they were redoing it.

Comment: @NathanOliver This isn't expression SFINAE, though. This is original recipe SFINAE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to the comments, your problem has nothing to do with expression SFINAE. This is bog-standard original-recipe SFINAE: you are checking the well-formedness of the *type* `int C::*`.

Before we start, you are parenthesizing it wrong. You want to apply `sizeof` to the result of `test`, not `==`:

```
enum { YES = (sizeof(IsClass<T>::test<T>(0)) == 1) };
             //     ^                      ^
```

(Also, [get rid of `void main()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c).)

Now, MSVC 2013 for some reason tries to do deduction and ignores the specified template argument if you do a qualified call:

```
    IsClass<T>::test<T>(0)
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

which is clearly a bug. I'm not sure why it's behaving this way, but then large parts of MSVC's frontend are held together by duct tape, so I'm not really surprised.

You don't need a qualified call anyway. Just write `test<T>(0)` and do an unqualified call:

```
enum { YES = (sizeof(test<T>(0)) == 1) };
```

which works on my MSVC 2013.